# How can I add user input to a checklist, but then place it in a label?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I would like to add user input to a list, which contains a label, which contains an input of type "checkbox"?

I have seen other questions, and used their code, but they don't work. Nothing happens when I click "Add".

Here is the JavaScript I found on W3Schools and in a similar question to my own, as well as the W3Schools link:

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_node_insertbefore.asp

```
function addToList() {
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(userInput);
    li.appendChild(text);
}
```

I **think** I understand that using this code I am not going to be able to place the user input inside of the input tag, followed by the label, so I would like to know if there is a way to do that.

Here is my JavaScript if you would like to see it:

```
function addToList() {
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var text = document.createTextNode(userInput);
    li.appendChild(text);

    var list = document.getElementById("cntr_List");
    list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

Here is the list itself (HTML of course) along with the input for text:

```
<div class="center" id="cntr">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Add an item</h2>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" style="width: 100%;" placeholder = "Add new task...">
            <span onclick="addToList()" style="cursor: pointer;" id="addBtn" >Add</span>
        </div>
        <ol style="list-style-type:none" id="cntr_list">
            <li><label onclick="openNav()"><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 1</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 2</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 3</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 4</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 5</label></li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

*If what I am doing is not feasible or bad HTML/JavaScript, please forgive me, for I am still learning. I am more than open to any suggestions you have that will give me the same or similar results. If there's no way to accomplish what I am attempting to achieve, feel free to say so, and tell me why.*

Comment: Are you really using jQuery ? try this, just for testing purpose : `$("#cntr_list").append('<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" /> test </label></li>');`

Comment: Also you should consider looking at Angular JS, Knockout JS and frameworks like these when you'll be more confident with JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Jquery. This is simple way to achieve.Try this one:

```js
$(function(){
$('#addBtn').on('click',function(){
$("#cntr_list").prepend('<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" />'+$('#userInput').val()+'</label></li>');
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="center" id="cntr">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Add an item</h2>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" style="width: 100%;" placeholder = "Add new task...">
            <span style="cursor: pointer;" id="addBtn" >Add</span>
        </div>
        <ol style="list-style-type:none" id="cntr_list">
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 1</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 2</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 3</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 4</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 5</label></li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: Did you check this ? @Kurt Attard

Comment: That works really well! I'd ask you if it's possible to put the user input at the top of this list, but I think I know how, and I don't really need to anyways.

Comment: I'll try and understand what on Earth most of that code means. If I have any trouble with it I'll just look it up. Thanks a million!

Comment: Anyway i updated the answer as you asked..It is showing top of the list..

Comment: (In case you're wondering why I haven't upvoted, I have. But my rep is still less than 15, so it's not available for view publicly yet.)

Comment: i am aware of that..thanks for the mind @Kurt Attard

Answer (score 1):

Just a slight modification in your code. You can do this with JS

```js
function addToList() { 
    var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
    var li = document.createElement("LI");
    var textnode = document.createTextNode(userInput);
    var x = document.createElement("INPUT");
    x.setAttribute("type", "checkbox");
    x.setAttribute("value", "ON");
     li.appendChild(x);
    li.appendChild(textnode);

    var list = document.getElementById("cntr_list");
    list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
    
}
```

```html
<div class="center" id="cntr">
    <div class="header">
        <h2>Add an item</h2>
        <input type="text" id="userInput" style="width: 100%;" placeholder = "Add new task...">
            <span onclick="addToList()" style="cursor: pointer;" id="addBtn" >Add</span>
        </div>
        <ol style="list-style-type:none" id="cntr_list">
            <li><label onclick="openNav()"><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 1</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 2</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 3</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 4</label></li>
            <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 5</label></li>
        </ol>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: That helps by a ton, but it's not adding a checkbox. Is it possible to fix that?

Comment: yes it is possible . you have create a input element and append in that list

Comment: @KurtAttard i have updated the code above, Now it will add checkbox too

Comment: Nice. I probably won't be using this, but it's really helpful because I've never knew that you could just set attributes like that. I upvoted you, but my rep is less then 15 so for now it won't show up. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```js
function addToList() {
  // Create you "li" element
  var li = document.createElement('li');

  // Create your label and insert it inside your li
  var label = document.createElement('label');
  li.appendChild(label);
  
  // Create your checkbox and insert it inside your label
  var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
  checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
  checkbox.classList.add('test');
  checkbox.value = 'ON';
  label.appendChild(checkbox);

  // Get the input value, and insert it inside your label
  var userInput = document.getElementById("userInput").value;
  var text = document.createTextNode(userInput);
  label.appendChild(text);
  
  // And finally append it to your list.
  // There was a typo here : 'cntr_list' was 'cntr_List', beware as JavaScript is case-sensitive.
  var list = document.getElementById('cntr_list');
  list.insertBefore(li, list.childNodes[0]);
}
```

```html
<div class="center" id="cntr">
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Add an item</h2>
    <input type="text" id="userInput" style="width: 100%;" placeholder="Add new task...">
    <span onclick="addToList()" style="cursor: pointer;" id="addBtn">Add</span>
  </div>
  <ol style="list-style-type:none" id="cntr_list">
    <li><label onclick="openNav()"><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 1</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 2</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 3</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 4</label></li>
    <li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" class="test" /> Item 5</label></li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you really using jQuery ? try this, just for testing purpose :

`$("#cntr_list").append('<li><label><input type="checkbox" value="ON" /> test </label></li>');`

just tested it, it works : https://jsfiddle.net/ng1unsoh/

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select null element on `var list = document.getElementById("cntr_List");` cause that should be `var list = document.getElementById("cntr_list");`